# Templating multiple yum .repo files with Ansible template module

Tags: jinja2, ansible

I am attempting to template yum .repo files. We have multiple internal and external yum repos that the various hosts we manage may or may not use.

I want to be able to specify any number of repos and what .repo file they will be templated in. It makes sense to group these repos in the same .repo file where they have a common purpose (e.g. all centos repos)

I am unable to determine how to combine ansible, yaml and j2 to achieve this. I have tried using the ansible 'with_items', 'with_subelements' and 'with_dict' unsuccessfully.

**YAML data**

```
yum_repo_files:
- centos:
  - name: base
    baseurl: http://mirror/base
  - name: updates
    baseurl: http://mirror/updates
- epel:
  - name: epel
    baseurl: http://mirror/epel
```

**Ansible task**

```
- name: create .repo files
  template: src=yumrepos.j2 dest="/etc/yum.repos.d/{{ item }}.repo"
  with_items: yum_repo_files
```

**j2 template**

```
{% for repofile in yum_repo_files.X %} {# X being the relative index for the current repofile, e.g. centos = 0 and epel = 1 #}
{% for repo in repofile %}
name={{ repo.name }}
baseurl={{ repo.baseurl }}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Have you considered using http://docs.ansible.com/assemble_module.html instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

user24364's answer helped solve half the issue, I then used some python methods to get the correct data out of the lists and dicts.

Giving the full filename 'centos.repo' rather than 'centos' simplified the logic (and aligned better with the logic for other tasks):

```
yum_repo_files:
- centos.repo:
  - name: base
    baseurl: http://mirror/base
  - name: updates
    baseurl: http://mirror/updates
- epel.repo:
  - name: epel
    baseurl: http://mirror/epel
```

The .iterkeys() and .next() methods are used on items to get the repo filenames out of the list of dicts:

```
- name: create .repo files
  template: src=yumrepos.j2 dest="/etc/yum.repos.d/{{item.iterkeys().next()}}"
  with_items: yum_repo_files
```

The .itervalues() method is used to get the list of dicts containing all the keys/values for each given repo:

```
{% for repofile in item.itervalues() %}
{% for repo in repofile %}
[{{repo.repo}}]
name={{ repo.name }}
baseurl={{ repo.baseurl }}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I also added some other tasks to clean up unmanaged files, etc. Once I've sanitised the code, I'll post it to the ansible galaxy as nobody else seems to have shared such a role.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `with_items` with the template module the special variable `item` will be passed into your jinja template.

Try this:

```
{% for repofile in item %} 
{% for repo in repofile %}
name={{ repo.name }}
baseurl={{ repo.baseurl }}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for this information. I can't seem to find it anywhere in the ansible documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Your files would be named as: *.repo.j2; then, you can use fileglob:

```
- name: create x template
- template: src={{ item }} dest=/tmp/{{ item | basename | regex_replace('.j2','') }}
- with_fileglob:
  - files/*.j2
```

Reference:

https://serverfault.com/questions/578544/deploying-a-folder-of-template-files-using-ansible